# Civicrm webform to edit membership custom fields

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

I am trying to create a webform using the Webform Civicrm Integration module.  The form would allow users to edit custom fields associated with existing memberships.  Our members are required to attend an orientation sometime after signing up for their initial membership.  I would like to create a form that would allow users to enter the date of a Member's orientation session, which is a custom field associated with Memberships.  I can't figure out how to do this for an existing, already previously created membership.  Is this possible with Civicrm Webform?

If not, would it be possible using a membership directory profile instead (haven't been able to figure out a way to include the Orientation date custom field for a profile either, since it would involve combining Contact and Membership fields).

Any suggestions?

I am using Civicrm 4.7.29 in Drupal 7, with Webform CiviCRM Integration 4.21.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely possible with Webform CiviCRM! A few thoughts:

- upgrade to CiviCRM 5.3.1 or above (a security update)
- by giving members logins or by using the checksum token you can make it such that their all ready exisiting in the database details (Name, Address, Membership Type) are displayed to them - you decide if you want them to be able to update those
- of course in addition to filling out the blank Custom fields on the Membership;
- look to enable the custom fields on your Membership in the CiviCRM tab for your webform -> Membership section (on the left) -> at the bottom of it. Here is an example: that Checkbox ALM is a CiviCRM custom field on the entity Membership in this example. Look here to expose your custom date fields to your Webform.

  [image]